# How can I prepend some HTML to an element, then check if the HTML was prepended?

Tags: jquery

I have a global JS method that puts a * in front of every field marked as having class .fish-label

the code is:

```
var fishString = "<span class='fish-label'> * </span>";
$elements.each(function (index, value) {
            if ($(this).html().indexOf(fishString) != 0) {
                $(this).prepend(fishString);
            }
        });
```

This works in all browsers except for IE. IE capitalises injected HTML and also my quotes get mysteriously lost somewhere when I alert the html() value.

Is there a better, working way I can implement this? The idea is that if the function gets called twice, it won't add two asterisks.

Comment: Where does `prependString` come from? How is `elements` selected?

Comment: Oops, shoulda been fishString! And elements is just a selector for labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just search for the element like any other normal nested DOM element.

```
        var fishString = "<span class='fish-label'> * </span>";
        $elements.each(function() {
            if ($(this).children('span.fish-label').length === 0) {
                $(this).prepend(fishString);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `filter` the set of elements to exclude those which already have a `.fish-label` and prepend one to the remaining elements:

```
var fishString = "<span class='fish-label'> * </span>";
$elements.filter(function() {
    return !$(this).has(".fish-label").length;
}).prepend(fishString);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CcTAs/1/).

Answer (score 1):

To do this you could also do without the js.
For example, if a label like the first of each item you may use the following statement:

**html**

```
<label class="required" for="username">Username</label>
<input id="username" type="text" value="" name="username">
```

**css**

```
label.required:after {
    content: " *";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JellyBelly/WcyyK/)

Answer (score 0):

If this is UI-stuff only, you can use CSS functionality:

```
.fish-label:before {
    content: "* ";
}
```

See the work example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/7vxb5/1/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my content requires styling and you cannot use CSS to add html. Good thinking though!